# Cant execute a simple Laravel's cron job in hosting with Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel, php-carbon

First of all, sorry for my english, im not a native talker. I'm learning Laravel, and I got stuck in a little problem. I cant execute a very simple cron job in a Hosting with Cpanel. I have this code in Kernel.php:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {       
        \Log::info('This is a log');
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

I had enabled the Cron job in Cpanel, every one minute (* * * * *), and evidently something is executing, because every minute i have this error registered in the log (obviusly not my text):

```
[2020-04-19 18:47:26] local.ERROR: Declaration of Carbon\Translator::setLocale($locale) must be compatible 
with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale) 
{"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): 
Declaration of Carbon\\Translator::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with 
Symfony\\Contracts\\Translation\\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale) 
at /home/grupodem/bad-conf/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Translator.php:18)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}
```

The goal of this simple exercise that I wanted to do, was just try Cron Jobs in Cpanel. In fact, the code it's very simple, but it doesn't work anyway.
The PHP version of the server is 7.3.16 and the project is Laravel 7.

Thank you very much in advance! Best regards!
Lucas

Comment: It's not an issue with your CRON itself, it works. 
You have an issue with your code, can you try to do a composer update ?

Comment: Hi Octet, thanks for the answer! My Laravel installation was a fresh one, i have nothing but the Schedule function. Well... i have a "Hello world" controller, but is just a silly example. Anyway, I ran composer update, uploaded everything to the server and still throws me this error every minute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an issue with the cronjob. It's an issue with laravel.

Method 1:
Add "symfony/translation": "4.3.8" in your composer.json & run composer update

Method 2:
Run composer require symfony/translation:4.3
Then run composer update

This should fix the issue you are facing

Comment: Hi Sudharshan! Thanks for the reply! I tried to run your solution, but i had two errors that make think that Laravel 7.x is not compatible with Symfony Translation 4.3: 

Method 1, i had this error after the execution of composer update:
`- laravel/framework 7.x-dev requires symfony/http-kernel ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.7, 5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.0-BETA1, v5.0.0-BETA2, v5.0.0-RC1, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6].`
(and repeats for v7.0.0, 7.0.1, etc)
/
Method 2:
`- symfony/translation v4.3.0 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel[v5.0.7].`

Comment: Hi Lucas, are you using a beta release of laravel or a stable release? which exact laravel version have you installed? if it's a beta version there can be issues. I assume this is a dependency issue between your laravel & PHP installation. 

It seems a known issue already - https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31893

Can you try the steps suggested in the above link?

Comment: I created the laravel project with `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel`. The installed version of the project is 7.5.2. I thought that if i used `--prefer-dist` should install the last stable version. According to Wikipedia, the last stable version is 6.13, i really dont know if 7.5.2 is a stable version. Something to point, i created a 6.x project, with "symfony/translation": "4.3.8" and the cron is executed correctly... So, for now it's a valid solution for me, although it is not the most correct. Anyway, i will try the github post! Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's great. As I expected it's an issue with the unstable release. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! Best regards from Argentina!